# Command work, but have a error when used by sh

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have this script:

extract.sh:

```
ffmpeg –i $1 –ss $2 –t $3 –c:v copy –c:a copy $4
```

If I type

```
ffmpeg –i full.mp4 –ss 114 –t 30 –c:v copy –c:a copy out.mp4
```

All go well. But if I try

```
sh extract.sh full.mp4 114 30 out.mp4
```

I get :

```
ffmpeg version 2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  5 2014 11:41:48 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[NULL @ 0x2a20b00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'
–i: Invalid argument
```

What does sh do to the argument to make it unreadable in the script?

EDIT:

```
user@domain:~/test$ sh extract.sh cdr.mp4 0 7 generique.mp4
ffmpeg –i cdr.mp4 –ss 0 –t 7 –c:v copy –c:a copy generique.mp4
```

Comment: Try quoting it: `ffmpeg –i "$1" –ss "$2" –t "$3" –c:v copy –c:a copy "$4"`

Comment: @anubhava: Doesn t change anything.

Comment: just echo the whole command: `echo ffmpeg –i "$1" –ss "$2" –t "$3" –c:v copy –c:a copy "$4"`

Comment: @anubhava: Well, it doesn t seems to add anything at all... (see edit).

Comment: Does the script have DOS line endings?

Comment: First debugging step: `sh -x` instead of plain `sh`, see what's actually being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-writing the sh file, it seemed there was invisible character somewhere in it, which where included in the command.